# how to display all the possible data greater than the current date

Tags: php

```
$Date = date("m/d/Y");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service WHERE SType = 'Retreat' and Start_date > '$Date' ");
```

Start_date format is m/d/y also.

whats wrong with my code? all i want to do is to display all the possible data greater than the current date. but it always show all the data from the database.

Comment: What data type is the Start_date column?

Comment: phpaddict, how did you manage to have your MySQL database store dates in m/d/y format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date("Y-m-d") rather than date("m/d/Y").

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this: http://www.bigroom.co.uk/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql ?

The article suggests you consider doing something like

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM service WHERE SType = 'Retreat' and Start_date > FROM_UNIXTIME($Date)"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you use the **YYYY-MM-DD** format for dates in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you store your date. If its stored as a unixtime, then you simply do an equal or greater check and you are on your way.

PHP has some great functions to turn date into unixtime. Like [strtotime](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)